# Groovy SDK 2.5.7 on Win7 Pro w/Java JDK 8 update 211 - Groovy Console not launching

Tags: windows-7, installation, java, 64-bit, groovy

I installed the 64-bit Java SE 8 update 211 last week in preparation for installing Groovy.  I attempted to install the Groovy 2.5.7 SDK earlier today.  Initially, it recognized the 64-bit Java I previously installed then, displayed a message claiming it could not confirm the 64-bit version and subsequently installed the 32-bit binaries of Groovy.  The file "installed_versions" discusses this issue and states that users can overcome this problem merely by copying the correct/desired versions of the native launcher (in C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-2.5.7\Supplementary\native) into the Groovy\Groovy-2.5.7\bin directory.

Is this the preferred solution for me to utilize or recover the 64-bit version of Groovy ?  It reads as if this is but, it remains difficult for me to accept the fact that the 32-bit binaries were installed rather than their 64-bit counterparts.

Lastly, I cannot launch the Groovy Console from Windows.  However, I opened a Command Prompt, navigated to the "bin" directory of Groovy-2.5.7 and was able to launch the console from this location.

My Environment Variables are as follows:

GROOVY_HOME C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-2.5.7

JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211

PATH %PATH%; %GROOVY_HOME%\bin

PATHEXT (ends with...) ;.groovy;.gy

Please let me know...

Comment: Two obvious issues: 1/ You haven't added `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to your `%PATH%`, 2/ you have a space in `%PATH%`. Fix those and install groovy again.

Answer (score 0):

@DavidPostill - Yes, and thank you.  It was my oversight of %JAVA_HOME%\bin in %PATH%.  I checked %PATH% for the space yet, it was only a typo I made in describing my issues here.  The 64-bit Groovy is installed and Console launches.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! It looks like you registered and created a second account, which will interfere with things like your ability to comment within your thread and to accept your own answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts).